Tried to install dlib this error shows up
Terminal returns this when i trypip install dlib. Am trying to install face_recognition for a project it asked me to install cmake which I did but when I tried to install dlib this error occurs
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      <string>:210: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
      <string>:211: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
      <string>:212: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
        File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
        File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (dlib)

I even tried assigning environment variables for cmake. Or am I doing it wrong?

Never worked with the tools you are using, but from the error message, I would first double-check that cmake is available. Since it is called from within a Python process, I would check this by doing a which CMake.
